# add a specific set of javascript code to every single page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a fully functioning PHP system with various .php files handling different processes.
i need to add in a specific set of javascript code to every single page that's generated.
can any one tell me How to do this? is its possible thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your "system" should include same header for all of the pages. And put your javascript to that file.

like:

**header.php**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    // some script
  </script>

</head>
<body>
```

**index.php** (main file)

```
<?php

  include "header.php";

  // Content
  include "some_content.php";     

  include "footer.php";

?>
```

**footer.php**

```
  <div><p>My footer</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a php footer and include this to every page. Place the markup for the script in the footer. The benefit of placing your javascript in the footer is that the page will render the page before trying to execute the script, making your page seem to load faster.

For each page add `include "footer.php"`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above methods, you can do this by another method.

Save the javascript as a separate file(code.js) and then using

`<?php include("code.js"); ?>`

in each of your files.

Answer (score -1):

Create a master page which other pages will be included as child pages. In header of the master page the js files can be included and handled by checking you requested url
Example:

```
$requested_url = $_GET['requested_page'];
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="js_path/<?php echo "$requested_url.js" ?>" ></script>;
...
```